# Cors issue when running docker using babylonnet.sh

Tags: docker, api

I'm running a Tezos network locally using `babylonnet.sh`. Works fine, can query for example `./babylonnet.sh client list known addresses`. Also works in browser for example `http://127.0.0.1:8732/chains/main/blocks/head`.

When I try and run a local server, and connect I get a cors error:

```
localhost/:1
Failed to load http://localhost:8732/chains/main/blocks/head/context/contracts/tz1ZQu5ZwCBP6QeTDwkrUHiUBzHtXi9gFqGF/balance
: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
Origin 'http://localhost:8000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I can't see how to set the cors using `babylonnet.sh` docker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `babylonnet.sh` script accepts node options. You can inspect the node options via `tezos-node run --help`. The option you're looking for is:

`--cors-origin=ORIGIN`: CORS origin allowed by the RPC server via Access-Control-Allow-Origin; may be used multiple times

Comment: Thanks! I got it working using this: `./babylonnet.sh start --rpc-port 127.0.0.1:8732 --cors-origin=http://localhost:8000 --cors-origin=node:8732 --cors-origin=localhost:8732`. Just adding localhost:8000 didn't work because some of the containers were using node:8732. But great stuff, I can start building now

Comment: Also, I ran --help and could't find reference to cors. I can't find a reference on the docs too. Am I missing something? If it is missing it might be worth doing a pr. I'll look into that if so

Comment: I'm guessing you're looking in the script's help, but this is located in the help of `tezos-node config`. I think with the script you can use `./babylonnet.sh shell tezos-node config --help` to access this.